# Trying to store values and loop calculations from a function

Tags: python

The equation requires the previous output to calculate the next value.
Vi = V(i-1) + t((c*(V(i-1)^2)/m)-g). With V(0)=0  and all other values being defined I am not sure how to write a loop code that would store the previous value and then calculate the next iteration. I've tried a `def` approach but I could never figure out how to recall the previous calculation to use in the next step.

```
  Vi = Vo + Dt*((c*(Vo**2)/m)-g)
  return Vi
```

Comment: in the equation *Vi = V(i-1) + t((c*(V(i-1)^2)/m)-g)* what are **t**, **c**, **m** and **g**?

Comment: Sorry for not defining that! That the equation is for velocity so t=time, c = a constant, m=mass, g=gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive solution, where you define each value of `v` relative to the prior value, might look like this:

```
def calculate_v(i):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    v = calculate_v(i - 1)
    return v + t * (c * v ** 2 / m - g)
```

whereas an iterative solution, where you just re-calculate `v` `i` times, would look like:

```
def calculate_v(i):
    v = 0
    for _ in range(i):
        v = v + t * (c * v ** 2 / m - g)
    return v
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming t, c, m, and g are constants you can pass them to the recursive function:

```
def V(input, t, c, m, g) -> int:
    if input == 0: return 0
    return V(input - 1, t, c, m, g) + t( (c * (V(input - 1, t, c, m, g) ** 2) / m) -g)
```

Answer (score 0):

t=time, c = a constant, m=mass, g=gravity. `c`, `m`, `g` are universal constants; the initial condition is `Vo`.

You are updating the time. `t` here is a list.

Let's say `t = [i for i in range(10)]`.

Your goal is to get `V[i]`, which is a list of velocity at time `t[i]`. You can use a simple for loop:

Step 1:
Initialize `V` to be a list of zeros first.

```
V = [0]*len(t)
```

Step 2:
Calculate and populate `V` using a for loop.

```
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    V[i] = Vo + Dt[i]*((c*(Vo**2)/m)-g)
```

Step 3:

```
return V
```

Therefore if you want to use `def`, it would be:

```
def calculate_V(t):
    V = [0]*len(t)
    for i in range(0, len(t)):
        V[i] = Vo + Dt[i]*((c*(Vo**2)/m)-g)
    return V
```